# Access Azure ARM VM after adding public IP

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

This issue is concerning ARM VMs as this is what we will be using.

I have created a number of windows server VMs now, through both the portal and powershell, and specified a NIC with a public IP (and part of a VNet of course as well) in the process. I can then RDP using that public IP without issues.

The trouble starts if I remove the public IP. This will remove my RDP access to it. Fine so far. But then, if I want to connect to it, I enable the public IP again, which succeeds according to the portal and all status messages, but I still am not able to connect to my VM with that new public IP anymore. Why is that? It drives me mad - I've deleted more than 5 VMs now because I lost access to them this way. I have tried to redeploy after assigning a new public IP, and all sorts of other trouble shooting in the portal, but the outcome remains, I can't RDP anymore.

This same issue appears if I create a new VM, but with an existing NIC and public IP. Easy to do in powershell, VM spins up - but I can't RDP into the new VM.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Real killer, since I won't need constant public IP access to the VMs but I will need to be able to restore access to them obviously!

Comment: What about create a new Resource Group with the new VM and virtual network, then move your existing VM over?

Comment: How did you remove your public IP? How did you enable it again? And, how did you connect your VM? Specifically, did you download the .rdp file from the portal, or connect the VM through Visual Studio? I'm trying to reproduce your issue. I create a VM through the portal, and dissociate the public address. After that, I go to the network interface of the VM and enable public IP address. I have tried both using the old IP address and creating a new IP address. And, both run with no issue. I download the .rdp file directory through the Portal.

Comment: juvchan - I haven't tried moving into a new resource group, but that would seem like a workaround anyway... I'd kinda like to keep the existing one!

Comment: @JackZeng - I went to the nic and under public IP selected disable (from memory). I downloaded the rdp file from the portal to connect and entered the IP manually as well. I didn't realise you could connect through VS, I might try that. I don't get why it it doesn't work for me! Tried it a lot of times now, always the same. Maybe I should mention that it's the free trial subscription at the moment still, in case that makes a difference? BTW, the RDP just times out when I try and connect.

Comment: A free trial subscription does not make a difference in the case unless it's expired or used up all credits. Did you try **Boot diagnostics** on the portal or reset the remote access with PowerShell or Azure CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it. It appears the NSG rule allowing RDP connections inbound disappears at some point! Going to have to look into this a bit more, but just had the same case again, my trial subscription happened to expire and Azure stopped the VM, I restart it (after changing the subscription obviously...) and can't connect. And then I checked the NSG (which I haven't changed!), and the RDP rule has gone. Odd!